# Excel - convert incorrect date format

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a total of 3 dates which all come from outside my system and are formatted as `mm/dd/yy` which excel seems to have troubles picking-up correctly, occasionally mixing up the `dd` and `mm` values (eg. `7/1/17` can be the first of July 2017, but is at times captured as the 7th of January 2017).

I am looking for a way to format all dates as `yyyy-mm-dd` to avoid any mistakes at all, but am not having much success in reformatting with `date()` or `datevalue()`.

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Thanks,
A2k

Comment: Import the file instead of opening it; use the text import wizard to tell excel the proper format of the incoming dates.

Comment: not an option as the data is ripped off a website table and undergoes a VBA treatment before being saved to the final data sheet. If I were to make any changes, it would have to be a formula or VBA code while I am sanitizing the data.

Comment: Then either do it in your VBA code (probably the best way) or, read it into Excel as text, and then use the `Text-To-Columns` wizard to do the conversion.

Comment: Again, the question is "how" would I do it during the VBA conversion? I am not having any success with the above mentioned formulas and am running out of ideas how to reformat a date in VBA.

Comment: I suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide information that would make it easy to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149431/discussion-between-ron-rosenfeld-and-armitage2k).

Comment: See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B48wABTBebDLt0-OOs-_wNJRA9QF1x4_FiPGpGCNT8c/edit?usp=sharing (I will write it up, but it may be easier to look at)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[done in Google sheets, but Excel should be similar] Suppose the funky date sits in cell A2. I did the following (several steps could be taken out and embedded in other formulas, but I wanted it to be clear). In B2 I placed the position of the first slash (might be 2 or 3) as `=SEARCH("/",A2)`. In C2 I placed the position of the second slash as `=search("/",A2,B2+1)`. In D2 I can get the year as `=2000+right(A2,2)` (I am assuming year is always in 2000s, but this code actually handles if a2 ends in /2017). In E2 I have the month as `=mid(A2,B2+1,C2-B2-1)`. The day is in F2 as `=left(A2,B2-1)` Finally F2 gets `=date(D2,E2,F2)` and you can choose a date format from the cell formats to format it as yyyy-mm-dd as desired.

Comment: Flawless. Thank you very much, appreciate the effort.